# Maximum absolute value of sum of m n-th roots of unity

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, golden-ratio

Let $\omega, \omega^2,\dots,\omega^{n-1},1$ be $n$-th roots of unity, and consider
$$S_n(m):=\max_{1 \le i_1 < i_2 <\dots<i_m \le n}|\omega^{i_1}+\dots+\omega^{i_m}|$$
i.e. the maximal absolute value of the sum of $m$ different $n$-th roots of unity.

Based on computer calculations, I conjecture that $S_{2n+1}(m)=\phi_{n}(m)$, where $\phi_n(m)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)},2\le m\le n $ are the so-called 'golden numbers' which generalise the golden ratio. Geometrically, these are the ratios of the lengths of diagonals in a regular $(2n+1)$-gon to the side lengths.

Is anything known about this?

Comment: It feels like it would be pretty easy to prove that the maximum is attained when taking $m$ consecutive $n$th roots of unity. That would be a geometric series that equaled the "golden numbers".

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! I got it.